# Multipeer Connectivity VS Real-Time Matches

Tags: ios, gamekit, multipeer-connectivity

I'm in the planning phases for a card game, where multiple people (not many, maybe up to 6) would be able to play, each one taking a turn.

Ideally, all people would play the game in the same place, at the same time. Multipeer Connectivity Framework sounded ideal, but after reading in some posts that it's unreliable, and slow, I'm wondering if [Multi-Peer Matches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html) would be best or even an option.

Other than the obvious (one uses Bluetooth and Wifi, and the other Game Center), what are the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is that multipeer connectivity works well with up to 7 connections. However, connections do drop sporadically and you need to handle detecting that and automatically re-connecting. Also, you cannot maintain connections in the background so if one of the players jumps into another app and then comes back, their connection will have been dropped.

Alternatively, you could use [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/). It works on both iOS and Android and removes a lot of complexity from the developer.

It is able to use peer-to-peer connections where appropriate:

"Internally, the room sets up a peer-to-peer mesh network between participants where clients can communicate directly with each other, rather than through the Play Game services servers"

Comment: Thanks. So is Google Play Game Services more reliable, in terms of drop connections?

Answer (score 1):

Having to go through Game Center for local connectivity sounds a bit over the top, and well ... it is.

I'm involved in a project (2-3 player game) that is shipping soon, and Multipeer Connectivity has been ok so far. There are some rough corners and (like always) some WTF moments/bugs, but in the context of a game, I wouldn't stress it too much.

6 players could be a problem though. Most of the problems that you have read in various posts (I've been through most of them too) about the framework seem to be directly related to the number of connected peers.

Also, don't think that Game Center doesn't come with its own random moments of undefined/unexpected behaviour glory. I (and another engineer) spent a good amount of this past weekend trying to figure out some of these moments.

I would get rid of the (rather "big") dependency and stick to local networking until I have concrete data that it doesn't fit my purposes.

Hope I've been helpful.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. I wish I could mark both answers as the right answer.